# What is the best way to hold data for jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Some time ago I wrote some quick Jquery code to select and advert at random below

```
    $(function () {

    var theImages = [ '*****.jpg', '******.jpg', '*****.jpg' ];
    var theLinks = [ 'http://www.****.co.uk', 'http://www.****.co.uk', 'http://www.*****.co.uk' ]
    var theRandomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (theImages.length - 1));
    $("#ad1").attr('src','images/' + theImages[theRandomNumber]);
    $("a#adL1").attr('href', theLinks[theRandomNumber]);
    var theRandomNumber2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (theImages.length - 1));
    while (theRandomNumber == theRandomNumber2) {
            theRandomNumber2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (theImages.length - 1));
    }
    $("#ad2").attr('src','images/' + theImages[theRandomNumber2]);
    $("a#adL2").attr('href', theLinks[theRandomNumber2]);
    } );
    </script>
```

I now have this code on 29 HTML pages in a website. Every time a ad changes I have to change every page. Can someone give some advice on the best and quickest way to put parameters in to I only have to update one thing. Then all of the pages will read these parameters and know what to display.

Thanks Paul

Comment: Why not add variables to your function for each of your HTML elements (i.e. `#ad1`, `#a#adL1` etc.)

Comment: Would the jquery method '.data()' be useful here?

Comment: The generation of `theRandomNumber` is not uniform.

Comment: It will also cause an infinite loop if there's only one element inside `theImages`.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the javascript into a javascript (.js) file and include this in each of your HTML files like so:

```
<head>
   <script src="/RandomAdvert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a file such as my_ads.js

Then in the header of each page use

```
<script src="/your_path/my_ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```